# Monitor file operations

Tags: monitoring

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS which is a NFS-server, and an Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS as an workstation, and an NFS client.

- On the workstation, my home diretory is `/home/sitron`, a sub-directory on the `/`-partition, all local to my workstation.
- On the server I have an dir, `/opt/exports/home`, which is exported as an NFS-directory. This is mounted on my workstation as `/mnt/server_home/`.
- In my home dir (`/home/sitron`) I have symlinked some directories, like `/home/sitron/Pictures/ -> /mnt/server_home/sitron/Pictures`, `/home/sitron/Videos/ -> /mnt/server_home/sitron/Videos` and six others.

This is working fine, and have been for several years (when using Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04). However, the last couple of days I have discovered that files from `/home/sitron/Pictures/` has been moved to `/home/sitron`, all by itself! And also files from `/home/sitron/Videos/`! This operation runs until my hard-drive is full. This has happened twice, and I have not initiated it in any way.

How can I figure out why this is happening? What logfiles do I need to monitor, or are there any programs that might help in the search for the cause of this unexpected behavior?